# how to loop the trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN
DECLARE offset_val int ;
declare count_val int ;

SET @count_val  = ((SELECT COUNT(users.sk_user_id) FROM users); 
SET @offset_val =1;

WHILE offset_val <= count_val DO

  SET @userId  = (SELECT users.sk_user_id FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET  offset_val) ; 

  INSERT INTO `user_notification` (`sk_user_nofication_id`, `user_notification_text`, 
   `user_notification_gif`, `general_notification_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `status`, `time_stamp`)
  VALUES (NULL, 'hf', new.general_notification_text, 
    new.sk_general_nofication_id, @userId, 'general', 'unread', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

  SET offset_val = offset_val + 1 ;

END WHILE ;
END
```

Comment: are you sure you have a trigger this looks more like a procedure or finction

Comment: @nbk There are a couple of `NEW.*` columns in there, so it must be a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with SQL, you should think of data in *sets* instead of one row at a time.

For example, you don't need a loop at all in this case. You can copy all the rows you need in one operation:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `user_notification` (`sk_user_nofication_id`, `user_notification_text`, 
   `user_notification_gif`, `general_notification_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `status`, `time_stamp`)
  SELECT NULL, 'hf', NEW.general_notification_text, 
    NEW.sk_general_nofication_id, sk_user_id, 'general', 'unread', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  FROM users;
END
```

This inserts as many rows into `user_notification` as the number of rows that are returned by the `SELECT`.

Some of the columns in the select-list are from the `users` table, some are part of your `NEW.*` columns you can reference in the trigger, and some are constant values.

This is a common way of using `INSERT` to add a set of rows to a table.